# Can you cancel Access to Azure Active Directory if you have Office 365?

Tags: azure, office365

I added for testing purposes Access to Azure Active Directory in Windows Azure. Now I realize there is no button to cancel the subscription:

[image]

As discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21858028/windows-azure-active-directory-and-office-365-integration) "the underlying directory for Office 365 is Azure Active Directory (AAD). This means that if you have an Office 365 account, you already have a directory -or "tenant"- in AAD."

1) Does this mean that this particular subscription has always been there - just not visible?
2) Can you cancel it?
3) According to the [pricing list](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/?scenario=full) adding objects is free (Free up to 500,000 objects), Application Enhancements (Preview) and Access Control. At which point would I be billed? (I know Azure generally bills for usage, the question is what counts as the usage in this particular situation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) The Azure AD was created when you signed up for Office365. This Azure subscription however was created when you signed up for Azure. Azure subscription is required to manage the many aspects of Azure AD that aren't available in the O365 portal.

2) you can create a support ticket (type billing) to have the subscription cancelled. If it's a free trial subscription it will automatically get cancelled. If it's a pay-as-you-go - it won't cost you anything until you use paid services. Which takes us to your last question ...

3) general Azure AD usage is free. If you need paid services of Azure AD like multi-factor auth for users, application access, self-service password reset you will need to but Azure AD licenses. As a thumb rule - if you haven't turned on multi-factor auth for users and you haven't bought AAD basic or AAD premium licenses - you won't spend any money on Azure AD. The object limit is a cap.

Hope that helps