# How to remove or cancel "Access to Azure Active Directory" subscription?

Tags: azure, office365, azure-active-directory

My company use Office 365 Business Premium and I have admin role. I made a mistake by click Azure AD link and sign up. It create "Access to Azure Active Directory" subscription as image below.

- How can I cancel subscription ?
- Will I be charged for subscription ?

[Image : Azure AD Link in Office 365 Admin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHmZ7.png)

[Image : Subscription Info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FnHWZ.png)

Comment: Please see the question answered in detail [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28278117/can-you-cancel-access-to-azure-active-directory-if-you-have-office-365).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every O365 subscription is created on top of an Azure Active Directory that will handle the authentication for the accounts/users, as default it will be running in a free version that wont incur any extra costs for your subscription.

You can have access to that Azure AD that lies beneath the O365 subscription by having an Azure Subscription (trial or paid) set up on the same tenant, that is probably what you activated in the O365 admin panel. In this case you shouldn't be charged unless you agree/sign up for any paid subscriptions or services.

In case that you activate the Azure Active Directory Premium version (you are going to be charged 6$ user/month) or the Azure Active Directory Basic version (you are going to be charged 1$ user/month).

Here you have more info on how O365 handles authentication with Azure AD: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-manage-o365-subscription/  https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Understanding-Office-365-identity-and-Azure-Active-Directory-06a189e7-5ec6-4af2-94bf-a22ea225a7a9#BK_Cloud