# Azure. Hidden Subscriptions "Access to Azure Active Directory"

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-resource-manager

After I upgraded my Azure Active Directory role form Owner to User Access Administrator (by doing this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/elevate-access-global-admin) 2 subscriptions called "Access to Azure Active Directory" appeared in Management Groups tab. What are those? My other accounts don't have them.[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove or cancel "Access to Azure Active Directory" subscription?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38680483/how-to-remove-or-cancel-access-to-azure-active-directory-subscription)

Comment: I haven't seen those in quite a while, but checking some links it seems to be related to O365 subscriptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After elevating access, you will be able to access to all subscriptions and management groups in your directory.

The Azure AD was created when you signed up for Office365. This Azure subscription however was created when your tenant users signed up for Azure.

Try to click "Properties" under settings part of that subscription, maybe you can find the account admin of that subscription.